# make: Nothing to be done for `all' error for make file

Tags: c, makefile

I am writing a make file to run this:

```
gcc program_1.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -o program_1
./program_1
```

This is my makefile

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=-g 
LIBS= -lgsl -lgslblas
SOURCES=program_1.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=program_1

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
        ./$(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $@

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

However, I'm getting this error on running make:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

I read various tutorials on makefiles and the man make page and I'm still stuck. Please let me know if you have any suggestions to fix this. Thank you!

EDIT:
After Jonathan Leffler's suggestion

```
gcc -I/usr/include/gsl program_1.c -o program_1.o
/tmp/ccLJo81U.o: In function `main':
program_1.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_view_array'
program_1.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_view_array'
program_1.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `gsl_permutation_alloc'
program_1.c:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_get'
program_1.c:(.text+0x1b6): undefined reference to `gsl_linalg_LU_decomp'
program_1:(.text+0x1d6): undefined reference to `gsl_linalg_LU_invert'
program_1.c:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_get'
program_1.c:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `gsl_permutation_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program_1.o] Error 1
```

I understand that it is unable to recognise the GNU GSL library that I have used in program_1.c, only when I use make. Have you faced a similar problem before?

Comment: That's not an error; it's just a report that everything is up to date so there is nothing to do.  If you want to run the program too, then add `./$(EXECUTABLE)` indented by a tab after the `all:` line.

Comment: Note that to get a useful debuggable executable, you have to compile the object files with `-g` as well as link with `-g`.

Comment: Add a `clean:` target to the makefile that `rm $(EXECUTABLE)` and `rm $(OBJECTS)`. Then you can `make clean` to get rid of all of the generated files.  Once all of the generated files are gone, then `make` will have something to do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - incorporated your suggestions, thank you

Comment: the macros are being re-evaluated at each reference.  Suggest using ':=' so the macros are only evaluated once.

Comment: strongly suggest separating the compile step from the link step.   On the link step, when using (almost) any library,  there are two parameters that can be added to the end of the link step.  (I.E. last parameters)  (optional, if the library is in a standard location) is the '-LpathToLibraryDirectory'  and  not optional: '-llibraryShortName'  (note parameter letter is lowercase 'L')

Comment: targets, like 'all' and 'clean' do not produce an actual output file of that name.  Therefore, there should be a '.PHONY: all clean' statement early in the makefile.

Comment: the posted makefile will not re-compile anything if a header file changes.  Suggest adding a rule to create the dependancy files, include the dependancy files with a include statement, usually at the end of the makeifle. then change this '.c.o:' to %.o:%.c %.d   (where the .d is the extension used on the dependancy files) and update the compile statement to match.

Comment: @user3629249: The chances are high that GNU Make is in use, and then `.PHONY` is useful, and even if the `make` is not GNU Make, the `.PHONY` rule won't do any harm, but `.PHONY` is a GNU Make extension and there is no explicit mention of GNU Make in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've written your code correctly, using notations like `#include <gsl/gsl_XXXXX.h>` to include GSL headers (as documented in the [example program](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/An-Example-Program.html#An-Example-Program) in the GSL — GNU Scientific Library — documentation), then you don't need the `-I /usr/include/gsl` option — unless you've hidden the GSL headers in the `/usr/include/gsl/gsl` directory, which seems a little unlikely.

Your makefile should be approximately:

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall
LDFLAGS = 
LDLIBS  = -lgsl -lgslcblas
SOURCES = program_1.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
PROGRAM = program_1

all: $(SOURCES) $(PROGRAM)
        ./$(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

This is very close to what you've got.  I've renamed `EXECUTABLE` to `PROGRAM` so that the main names are the same length (silly, but…).  I removed the `.c.o` rule since `make` already knows how to compile C code to object files and uses a rule similar to what you show — the built-in rule includes an explicit `-c` flag, which you are currently missing.

The link line includes CFLAGS, and CFLAGS includes the `-g` option for including debug information in your build.

You already included the libraries after the object files; that is important and correct.

<sup>*Library name updated to `-lgslcblas` to match comments.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for helping me, Jonathan.
I changed my make file to make it the same as the one you suggested above. However, I'm getting this error now:

    `gcc -g -Wall  program_1.o -lgsl -lgslblas -o  program_1
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslblas
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [compute_inverse_matrix] Error 1`

I also added the include statements in my c file

Comment: You probably need to add a `-L /some/where` option to `LDFLAGS` but I can't begin to guess where your `gslblas` library is if the plain `gsl` library is found and the other is not in the same directory.  You'll need to hunt it down and add the appropriate name.

Comment: @JonathonLeffler - Thank you for this suggestion!
I used locate
`locate blas`
`/usr/include/gsl/gsl_blas.h`
`/usr/include/gsl/gsl_blas_types.h`
`/usr/include/gsl/gsl_cblas.h`
`/usr/lib/libgslcblas.a`
`/usr/lib/libgslcblas.so`
`/usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0`
`/usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0`

Added `LDFLAGS = -L /usr/include/gsl`

Same error persists

Comment: Your library is `libgslcblas.so` but you're trying to find `-lgslblas`; I think you'd do better with `-lgslcblas`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it! You saved the day :)

Comment: very good example of a simple makefile.  However, it will not compile any .c files if a header file is changed.   Needs to have the creation of the dependancy files and the incorporation of the dependancy files in the compile rule

Comment: you will probably need to add a generic compile rule, that includes a '-I/usr/include/gls' parameter so the compiler knows where to find the header files that are not in the standard /usr/include/ directory.

Comment: @user3629249: Actually, no.  If the code is written correctly, as shown in the examples, and contains `#include <gsl/gsl_header.h>` for each GSL header, then the fact that the headers are installed in `/usr/include/gsl` means that the compiler will find the GSL headers without any extra `-I` options.  Granted, it does not contain any dependencies for object files on headers.  That is readily fixed by those who know what headers are included. _[…to be continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  Personally, I don't usually worry about dependencies on system-installed headers (headers in `/usr/include/gsl`, for example).  When the library changes, I recompile everything, removing all the object files and local libraries.  When, as here, the program is a single source file, there probably aren't any local headers to deal with — there's no need for a header when there isn't a multiplicity (more than one) source file to use them. So, you're right that a bigger project with more source files would need a more complex `makefile`. This one is, I think, OK for the context.